# Getting a sequence of diffs between revisions with mercurial

Tags: automation, mercurial

I want to see a sequence of diffs between consecutive (non-identical) revisions of the same file in a mercurial repository. I can obviously do that by parsing the result of `hg log`, extracting the changesets, then reading those two lines at a time and issuing `hg diff -r $first_changset -r $second_changeset` in a loop.

But - is there a more straightforward/elegant/graphical way of achieving the same?

Note: Not annotate though - at least not what it does by default. I want to be able to see all changes of the same changeset bunched together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is with `hg export`, e.g.:

```
hg export -r reva:revb
```

This will actually give you an importable patch, but the extra meta information is often helpful.

The most general solution with the most configurable output is `hg log` with templates, e.g.:

```
hg log -r reva:revb -T '{diff()}\n'
```

The `diff()` template function takes optional arguments to specify include and exclude patterns. See `hg help templates` for details.

Note that this also works with `-G` and will draw a dependency graph alongside the diffs. Even when the graph is linear, this can help in finding the beginning and end of a diff. Obviously, you can also add further information to the template, such as revision number, hash, commit message, and author.

Normally, `hg diff -c` is intended for showing the diffs made *by* a revision, but unfortunately that does not work when you have multiple revisions.

Comment: Can I make that work for just those revisions which altered an individual files in the repository?

Comment: You can use revsets to only include revisions that affect that file, e.g. `reva:revb and file(pattern)`.